# Use translateX() to move on the X axis, it also moves the Y axis

Tags: html, css

I simply want to make an animation to move the arrow on the x-axis. I want to move the arrow from left to right.
But when using:

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(4%);
```

It also moves on the Y axis too. Why does this happen, and how could I fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/f0LkLLmb/

```
<div class='contenedor_flecha_prev'>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left flecha_izqu" ></i>
</div>

.contenedor_flecha_prev{
position: fixed;
height: 80%;
width: 8%;
background: black;
bottom: 10%;
min-width: 35px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 90;
opacity:0.5;
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.fa.fa-chevron-left.flecha_izqu{
font-size: 55px;
color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
opacity: 1;
}

.contenedor_flecha_prev:hover .fa.fa-chevron-left.flecha_izqu {
-webkit-animation: flecha_izquierda 1.5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
}


@-webkit-keyframes flecha_izquierda {
50%   { 
-webkit-transform: translateX(4%);
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're starting from `translate(-50%,-50%)` in the initial CSS for `.fa.fa-chevron-left.flecha_izqu`, and when you specify a new `transform` it overwrites the old one entirely. So you're animating from `translate(-50%,-50%)` to `translate(4%,0)`.

In your animation, specify the y-axis, too, which is just `-50%`

```css
.contenedor_flecha_prev {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80%;
  width: 8%;
  background: black;
  bottom: 10%;
  min-width: 35px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 90;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.fa.fa-chevron-left.flecha_izqu {
  font-size: 55px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.contenedor_flecha_prev:hover .fa.fa-chevron-left.flecha_izqu {
  -webkit-animation: flecha_izquierda 1.5s infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes flecha_izquierda {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(4%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='contenedor_flecha_prev'>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left flecha_izqu"></i>
</div>
```